# C# Random of cordinates is linear

Tags: c#

My code is to generate random cordinates of lat and long within a bound:

```
        Random lastLat = new Random();

        Random lastLon = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            int lat = lastLat.Next(516400146, 630304598); //18.51640014679267 - 18.630304598192915

            int lon = lastLon.Next(224464416, 341194152); //-72.34119415283203 - -72.2244644165039

            SamplePostData d0 = new SamplePostData();
            d0.Location = new Location(Convert.ToDouble("18." + lat), Convert.ToDouble("-72." + lon));
            AddPushpin(d0);

        }
```

My output looks like this:
[http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7504/capturerkv.png http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7504/capturerkv.png](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/7504/capturerkv.png)

Is there something wrong with how my numbers are generated?

Comment: Both randoms are created within one tick (100 nanoseconds) of each other, so start with the same seed. as such, they will produce exactly the same values on calling Next(), resulting in that lovely y = -x line you have there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jørn's answer gave the problem, but not the solution: just use a single instance of `Random`:

```
Random rng = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    int lat = rng.Next(516400146, 630304598);
    int lon = rng.Next(224464416, 341194152);
    SamplePostData d0 = new SamplePostData();
    d0.Location = new Location(18d + lat / 1000000000d,
                               -72d - lon / 1000000000d);
    AddPushpin(d0);
}
```

(I've changed the way of using the result, too - there's no need to convert to and from a string to achieve what you want. An alternative would be to call `Random.NextDouble` instead and multiply it by the size of the desired range, then add a base value.)

If you're calling routine multiple times, you should probably use a single instance of `Random` across those multiple calls. Beware though: `Random` in .NET is not thread-safe. Ideally you should have a single instance per thread. See my [article on randomness](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more details of how to handle `Random`.

Comment: This worked, but I still dont understand why one Random object worked perfectly and not two.

Comment: The random number generator is just a series of output for a specific mathematical calculation. And if you initialize that random number generator with the same values it will always produce the same output. In your case it seems your computer was fast enough to initialize both of your random instances with the same value so everytime you call them both in parallel they will produce the same output value.
When using the Next function you always get the next value of that calcualtion which is why using only one works.

Comment: you could use as seed the following: (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF

Comment: @JonSkeet thats a very good question, but 32767 is a good seed, it would give you enough variation so you dont get similar coordinates.

Comment: @Oakcool: I disagree. Your code is actually *worse* than just calling `new Random()` which uses more bits from the current time. The answer is to *not* use the current time more than once in the program. I've got an article on this which I'll link into the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are initializing both of your `Random` instances without an explicit seed, causing them to return the same stream of pseudo-random numbers. What you are doing now, is equivalent of using `DateTime.Now` as the seed for both instances. As modern computers tend to execute code *really* fast, you end up with the same seed in both instances.

If you use a single `Random` instance for generating both lang and long you should see a much more "random" distribution.

Comment: @Shawn Mclean: How much change do you think there is in the current time between the execution of line 1 and line 2?

Comment: Random() is seeded with time by default.

Comment: The problem is the two objects are initialized with the same time seed.

Comment: @Mark: There is surely MUCH more than one tick between the two lines.

Comment: @Foxfire: Don't confuse the *precision* of a tick counter with its *accuracy*. Just because ticks occur doesn't mean that they'll be visible. Try filling a list with consecutive calls to `Environment.TickCount`, and then print them out... you'll see lots of repeated values.

Comment: @Foxfire: Read this article by Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. In fact I tried the original setup and it worked on my computer without producing the same values as in the example above. However Mark and Jon are correct and it seems that it is likely than on other machines the creation of a new Random is actually fast enought to fall into one update of the system Tickcount.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use two different `Random` objects. Draw both latitude and longitude from the same `Random`.

```
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    int lat = random.Next(516400146, 630304598); //18.51640014679267 - 18.630304598192915
    int lon = random.Next(224464416, 341194152); //-72.34119415283203 - -72.2244644165039

    SamplePostData d0 = new SamplePostData();
    d0.Location = new Location(Convert.ToDouble("18." + lat), Convert.ToDouble("-72." + lon));
    AddPushpin(d0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you are creating two Random objects at the same time causing them to be seeded with almost the same Time seed.

Use just ONE object.